# Dimension of the space $L(D)$ for $D$ a hyperplane divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $q=r^2$ with $r$ an odd power of a prime.  For the curve $X$ defined over $\mathbb F_q$ by the equation

$$x^{r+1}+y^{r+1}+z^{r+1}=0$$

we have the following $\mathbb F_q$-rational intersection points between the curve and the line $z=0$:

$$P_i=[\beta_i:1:0],\ \ \  i=1,\ldots,r+1$$

with $\beta_i\in\mathbb F_q$ and $\beta_i^{r+1}=-1$.

My question is how to prove that for the divisor $D=P_1+\ldots+P_{r+1}$ on $X$ with $P_i$ an arbitrary point we have

$$L(D-P_i)=2$$

and

$$L(D)=3.$$

Note that the divisor $D$ is the intersection divisor of $z=0$ with $X$. I don't know if this is relevant or I was wrong in some argument.

Thanks all for any suggestion.